# Ruby: Embedded Ruby Array of hashes to JSON

Tags: ruby, json

I am trying to convert the Ruby array of hashes to a JSON and return it.

What I've tried so far:

```
hash ={}
user.attributes.each_pair do |key, value|
  if(key == 'auth_id')
     hash[key] = value
  elsif (key == 'useractivity')
     # How do I get to the Key's array of useractivities from here?
     # {useractivities : [{id:,:name},{:id,:name}]}
  end
end
return hash.to_json
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show what you're starting off with and what you're trying to get it to look like?

Comment: Are you looking for: `hash[key] = value[:useractivities]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
hash ={}
user.attributes.each_pair do |key, value|
  if(key == 'auth_id')
     hash[key] = value
  elsif (key == 'useractivity')
     value.each {|inner_hash|   do_something_on_inner_hash}

     # How do I get to the Key's array of useractivities from here?
     # {useractivities : [{id:,:name},{:id,:name}]}
  end
end
return hash.to_json
```

Comment: Ah, Ok. But If I want my inner hash to be a part of the hash, How can I do that? The issue is that whenever I try to display the useractivity in my route, I always get an empty JSON.

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and sample output.